# How to generate bitcoin addresses on the command line or with python?

Tags: linux, address-generation

Is there an easy way to generate bitcoin addresses with a commmand-line tool? I am interested in the following requirements:

1. Reliable, secure and standards conform, with good entropy
2. Generates private and public keys for the corresponding bitcoin address
3. Can BIP38 Encrypt
4. Can produce in bulk
5. Runs in linux
6. Nice to have: python library
7. Nice to have: can save QR codes as images (png) for private / public keys
8. Nice to have: fast, and non-interactive (all parameters on command line)

Basically I am looking for a replacement for https://www.bitaddress.org/, for the command line.

Comment: what did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core's bitcoon-cli provides command-line functionality for manipulating a wallet, including creating addresses.  Running a full bitcoin-core node also means you can connect programmatically via Python to it using json-rpc to create addresses.